# VB.Net SQL Query - I am trying to Concatenate two columns however I am running into issues

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-like, sql-in

Below is a query I am trying to execute. I get an error

> ClassItem is not a column name.

Please can somebody let me know where I am going wrong in this query.

```
SELECT 
    *, CONCAT([Cabin], [Item]) AS ClassItem 
FROM 
    FQR_RAW_1 AS ClassItem 
WHERE 
    ClassItem IN ('%JCHML - Child Meal%', '%WCHML - Child Meal%', '%YMC - Beef%', '%YMC - Chicken%', '%YMC - Fish / Shellfish%', '%YMC - Pork%', '%YMC - Regional Taste (Non Veg)%', '%YMC - Regional Taste (Veg)%', '%YMC - Vegetarian%')  
    AND [Origin Region] LIKE 'USA%'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reuse a column defined in the `select` clause in the `where` clause - here, that's `ClassItem`.

Another problem is that you cannot use `IN` with wildcard `%`, which seems to be your intent here. You might be looking for a series of `OR`  condition instead:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT([Cabin], [Item]) as ClassItem 
FROM FQR_RAW_1  
WHERE 
    (
           CONCAT([Cabin], [Item]) LIKE '%JCHML - Child Meal%'
        OR CONCAT([Cabin], [Item]) LIKE '%WCHML - Child Meal%'
        OR CONCAT([Cabin], [Item]) LIKE '%YMC - Beef%'
        OR CONCAT([Cabin], [Item]) LIKE '%YMC - Chicken%'
        OR CONCAT([Cabin], [Item]) LIKE '%YMC - Fish / Shellfish%'
        OR CONCAT([Cabin], [Item]) LIKE '%YMC - Pork%', 
        OR CONCAT([Cabin], [Item]) LIKE '%YMC - Regional Taste (Non Veg)%'
        OR CONCAT([Cabin], [Item]) LIKE '%YMC - Regional Taste (Veg)%'
        OR CONCAT([Cabin], [Item]) LIKE '%YMC - Vegetarian%'
    ) 
    AND [Origin Region] LIKE 'USA%'
```

Note that I also removed the table alias, that is actually not needed in the query, and that was identical to the column alias - although SQL supports that, this is a bit confusing. If you need to alias the table for some reason, then use another alias.

Comment: Is there any reason to Concat([Cabin], [Item]) as ClassItem , seen as we never call ClassItem ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-use an alias in the same query.  One simple solution is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM (SELECT r.*, CONCAT([Cabin],[Item]) as ClassItem
      FROM FQR_RAW_1 AS r
     ) r
WHERE ClassItem IN ('%JCHML - Child Meal%', '%WCHML - Child Meal%', '%YMC - Beef%', '%YMC - Chicken%', '%YMC - Fish / Shellfish%', '%YMC - Pork%', '%YMC - Regional Taste (Non Veg)%', '%YMC - Regional Taste (Veg)%', '%YMC - Vegetarian%') AND
      [Origin Region] LIKE 'USA%'
```

Comment: Is the stray 'r' after from a typo or intended?

Comment: @dkettle01 . . . It is not "stray".  It is a table alias.